# How can I move my RSS Feeds folder in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

When I try dragging my RSS Feeds folder in Outlook 2010 to a local [PST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Storage_Table) file I get a message saying "Special and default folders cannot be moved".

I need to move it as it is taking up too much space in my mailbox on the server. What other options are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite easy really - File - Account Settings - RSS Feeds tab.
duh